# FoldList like primitive in J

Tags: j

Mathematica has a built-in function called `FoldList` [FoldList function description](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html). Is there a similar primitive verb in J?

(I know that J has a `^:` verb, which is like `Nest` and `FixedPoint`.)

To clarify my question, J has dyadic verb, so usually `u / x1 x2 x3` becomes  `x1 u (x2 u x3)`, which works just like `FoldList`, with reverse order.

Except if the function `u` takes `y`, in a different shape from `x`. In `FoldList` there is an initial `x`. In J, if x3 is a different shape, one has to rely on `<` to pack it together. For example, one has to pack and unpack

```
   [list =. (;/ 3 3 4 3 3 34),(< 1 2)
+-+-+-+-+-+--+---+
|3|3|4|3|3|34|1 2|
+-+-+-+-+-+--+---+

   tf =: 4 : '<((> x) , >y)'


   tf/ list
+----------------+
|1 2 3 3 4 3 3 34|
+----------------+
    tf/\ |. list
+---+------+--------+----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
|1 2|1 2 34|1 2 34 3|1 2 34 3 3|1 2 34 3 3 4|1 2 34 3 3 4 3|1 2 34 3 3 4 3 3|
+---+------+--------+----------+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

which is kind of inconvenient. Any better solutions?

Comment: And `<` is not a universal solution. Suppose we want to insert  + in the list 1 2 3 4 with initial value 1 2. Box and unbox seem inefficient.

Comment: need to correct the mistake: u / x1 x2 x3 is x1 u x2 u x3, because J evaluates expression from right to left, so it becomes x1 u (x2 u x3), which is as Eelvex pointed out "right folding"

Comment: The first two elements of FoldList are `x` and `f(x,a)`. In J those two have to be of the same "kind". The inconvenience comes from J's data structures not from the lack of a `FoldList` verb.

Comment: Agreed (and +1'd) with @Eelvex comment that this boils down to J's type system.  In J, all arrays are rectilinear (orthotopic, i.e. rectangular in the N-dimensional sense) and homogeneous in type. 

So the question can be distilled to "how can I collect unlike things in J", and the answer to Zhe's original observation that boxing is required (collecting unlike things is the raison d'etre of boxes in J).

As to inconvenience: well, this use-case has been noticed before, and various conveniences developed: 

http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2006-May/002245.html

Answer (score 2):

`u/\` comes very close (if you don't mind the right folding):

```
+/\ 1 2 3 4
1 3 6 10

*/\1+i.10
1 2 6 24 120 720 5040 ...

 (+%)/\7#1. NB. continued fraction of phi
 1 2 1.5 1.66667 1.6 1.625 1.61538
```

**edit** on your edit:

The first two elements of `FoldList` are `x` and `f(x,a)`. In J those two have to be of the same "kind" (shape+type) if you want them on the same list. The inconvenience comes from J's data structures not from the lack of a `FoldList` verb. If you exclude `x` from the list, things are easier:

```
FoldListWithout_x =: 1 : 'u/ each }.<\y'

   ; FoldListWithout_x 1 2 3 4
┌─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│┌─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┬─┐│
││1│2│││1│2│3│││1│2│3│4││
│└─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┴─┘│
└─────┴───────┴─────────┘
   >+ FoldListWithout_x 1 2 3 4
3 6 10
   (+%) FoldListWithout_x 7#1
┌─┬───┬───────┬───┬─────┬───────┐
│2│1.5│1.66667│1.6│1.625│1.61538│
└─┴───┴───────┴───┴─────┴───────┘
```

The next logical step is to include a boxed `x` *after* making the folds, but that will either require more complex code or a case-by-case construction. Eg:

```
FoldList =: 1 :'({.y) ; u FoldListWithout_x y'
+ FoldList 1 2 3 4
┌─┬─┬─┬──┐
│1│3│6│10│
└─┴─┴─┴──┘
; FoldList 1 2 3 4
┌─┬─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│1│┌─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┬─┐│
│ ││1│2│││1│2│3│││1│2│3│4││
│ │└─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┴─┘│
└─┴─────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

vs

```
FoldList =: 1 :'(<{.y) ; u FoldListWithout_x y'
+ FoldList 1 2 3 4
┌───┬─┬─┬──┐
│┌─┐│3│6│10│
││1││ │ │  │
│└─┘│ │ │  │
└───┴─┴─┴──┘
; FoldList 1 2 3 4
┌───┬─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│┌─┐│┌─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┐│┌─┬─┬─┬─┐│
││1│││1│2│││1│2│3│││1│2│3│4││
│└─┘│└─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┘│└─┴─┴─┴─┘│
└───┴─────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Dan Bron's comment deserves an answer. It is discussed with some solutions in http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2006-May/002245.html

if we define an adverb (modified from the link above)

```
   upd =: 1 : 0
:
 u&.> /\ ( <"_ x),<"0 y
)
```

then

```
1 2  , upd |. 3 3 4 3 3 34 
┌───┬──────┬────────┬──────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┐
│1 2│1 2 34│1 2 34 3│1 2 34 3 3│1 2 34 3 3 4│1 2 34 3 3 4 3│1 2 34 3 3 4 3 3│
└───┴──────┴────────┴──────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────┘
```